# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 924

Tags: java, arrays

I am reading a txt file and trying to save it into a 2-dimensional(2D) array, but got the error,the .txt file is saved definitely as a 100*997 array splitted by \t.
It says

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   924!

```
int i=0;

double[][] vector=new double[100][997];

String line;

while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
    line=line.trim();
    String[] words = line.split("\t");
    for (int j=0; j<997; j++) {

       vector[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(words[j]);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Why is it out of bounds at 924?

Thank you very much!

Comment: so each line has 997 doubles? better check your data

Comment: Use a debugger to confirm what you are expecting

Comment: Maybe print the length of words array

Comment: i=99  j=923 0.0021979621488, this means that I have successfully saved 99 rows, only the 100th row failed at column 925.

Comment: what is the meaning of this comment?

Comment: sorry, this is my first question here, I pushed the data before I finished the comment

Comment: if `i` is equal to `100` then this would be the 101st row, thus exceeding your array size

Answer (score -2):

line=line.trim();

Probably, the line has only 924 words after trim();

This would throw an error on reference to words[924].

Comment: I checked data file, the last row has exact 997 words,all of them are doubles

Comment: also at the beginning I didn't have line=line.trim(), same error

Comment: Sorry! After I double checked the txt file, I found it IS NOT complete which means I didn't use .close() when I tried to write the file, so the data is not completely written into the file ended on 924, that is why I got the error!